# How to resolve circular dependencies: Vuex requiring js modules that rely on Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a `Vuex` store that imports `notifications.js` module that needs `Vuex.store.state` to operate. How would you resolve this?

Right now I'm resolving this circular dependency by passing `store.state` as a prop. Is there a better solution?

This method requires `store.state` to be imported in every file that's using `new Notification()` just so I can pass it as a prop.

#### Vuex store

```js
import Notification from './notifications.js'

actions: {
  someAction (store) {
    new Notification({
      name: 'notificationName',
      state: store.state
    })
  }
}
```

#### notifications.js

```js
// Importing Vuex store creates circular dependency
// import store from './store.js'

class Notification {
  // Needs store.state to operate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code. you can use that:

```
[types.order.mutations.UPDATE_ORDERS_LIST]: (state, payload) => {
state.ordersList.find(el => {
if (el.reference_number === payload.reference_number) {
el.status = payload.status;
el.status_locale = payload.status_locale;
el.is_cancelable = payload.is_cancelable;
}
});
}
[types.operations.mutations.MUTATE_EXCHANGE_CURRENCIES]: (state, payload) => {
let data = [];
payload.wallets.forEach(elem => {
if (elem.is_change_active && elem.currency.iso !== "IRR") {
data.push(elem);
}
});
state.exchangeCurrencies = data;
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: I don't see how this code solves the problem

Comment: You should also add some details or comment about your code, so everyone can understand why and how it solves the issue.

Comment: I will check it. I had misunderstand